# Force all execution to pause using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

I am making a chrome extension that aims to pause execution of a tab if it inactive after some time in order to stop if from consuming resources.
By "Pause", I mean something like `debugger`, however, `debugger` does not seem to work unless the developer inspector tool is open.

Is there anyway to stop a tab from consuming resources until the user goes to that tab and click on something (like the play button on debugger)

PS: I want to make this because there a synonym/dictionary website that slowly consumes 5GB of RAM even if it is left inactive for half an hour.

Comment: "debugger does not seem to work unless the developer inspector tool is open" --- Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any error message(s).

Answer (score 0):

The only way is using `alert()` or `prompt()`. <kbd>Enter</kbd> may be used to confirm and continue executing.